# Proof of: Because $I$ is dense in $R$ there exists a sequence $\{x_n\} \subset I$ with $\{x_n\} \to r$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

In a passage from some school slides I have written:

consider an arbitrary $r \in Q$. Because $I$ is dense in $R$ there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}  \subset I$  with $\{x_n\} \to r$.

This seems sensible but I am unsure where to start a proper proof.

Comment: Begin with the definition of "dense".  What does that mean?

Comment: What is $I$? And what is your definition of dense?

Comment: Ok the definition of dense I was working with was: for every two real numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$, there exists a irrational number $j$ satisfying $a<j<b$ . Now I am trying to prove the equivalence of the two definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Using the definition you provided in the comments:

Consider any $r \in \Bbb R$.  By the density of the rationals, we may construct a sequence as follows:

- Select a rational $x_1$ such that $r - 1 < x_1 < r$
- Select a rational $x_2$ such that $r - 1/2 < x_2 < r$
- $\vdots$
- Select a rational $x_n$ such that $r - 1/n < x_n < r$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$

The resulting sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this by definition?

For any $r\in R$, it is a limit point of $I$. So by definition there exists a sequence in $I$ with limit $r$. And then $r\in Q$ implies $r\in R$.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Often, density is defined in terms of neighborhoods rather than sequences, in which case the statement is slightly less immediate.

Comment: The definition of $I$ being dense in $\mathbb{R}$ says that for every point $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we either have that $x$ is a limit point of $I$ (for which we have our sequence) or that $x\in I$. However for the second case the sequence $a_n = x$ will do (or if one requires $a_n \not\in I$ then one must do some more work to construct the sequence).

Comment: Ok the definition of dense I was working with was: for every two real numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a < b$, there exists a irrational number $j$ satisfying $a<j<b$ . Now I am trying to prove the equivalence of the two definitions.

Comment: Well, Omnomnomnom has provided the answer